# Incoming blocked ports DD-WRT router

Tags: windows, router, port-forwarding

We have an DD-WRT router. Some servers, devices in our network must be accessable from outside. They are accessable on different ports (80, 143, ...).

I configured the router and added some rules under Port Forwarding but it doesn't works always.

Like example:
From 1234 to 10.0.0.46:80 works
From 1723 to 10.0.0.10:1723 works also
From 40001 to 10.0.0.12:80 doesn't work

I checked my ISP and they aren't blocking any ports (for us)... I also rebooted the router after saving the settings..

In our network we have 1 server that is a DNS / DHCP. It has it's own firewall, but I thought it was specific for that server?

If I visit my fixed WAN ip (from inside), I can access all of the ports. (1234, 1723, 40001, ...). But if I want to connect from outside, 40001 doesn't ..

What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you connect to 10.0.0.12:80 locally?

Comment: I can.. And even with the wan ip from inside

Comment: Then it is some FW rule. Since it is NAT, the request will look like its coming from the DD-WRT anyway, and since you can call the WAN IP from within, it must be some rule on the router box. Maybe try and change the port just to be sure.

Comment: I changed 40001 to 888, but neither..